# Solving Maximum length of repeated subarray recursively

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a naive recursive solution for the leetcode problem [Maximum length of repeated subarray](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-length-of-repeated-subarray/). The question is

> Given two integer arrays nums1 and nums2, return the maximum length of a subarray that appears in both arrays.
> Example 1: Input: nums1 = [1,2,3,2,1], nums2 = [3,2,1,4,7]
> Output: 3
> Explanation: The repeated subarray with maximum length is [3,2,1].

> Example 2: Input: nums1 = [0,0,0,0,0], nums2 = [0,0,0,0,0]
> Output: 5

My code:

```py
 def findLength(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> int:
        if not nums1 or not nums2:
            return 0
        if nums1[0] == nums2[0]:
            return 1 + self.findLength(nums1[1:], nums2[1:])
        else:
            return max(self.findLength(nums1[1:], nums2), self.findLength(nums1, nums2[1:]))
```

My code fails the test case `[0,1,1,1,1] [1,0,1,0,1]`, returning `3` when the right answer is `2` ([0,1]). Intuitively I know this is because in the simulation

```
[0,1,1,1,1] 
 ^-------|
[1,0,1,0,1]      | -- match, max length +1
   ^         
______

[0,1,1,1,1] 
   ^----------|
[1,0,1,0,1]      | -- match, max length +1
     ^----------|

______

[0,1,1,1,1]
     ^-------------|
[1,0,1,0,1]      | -- mismatch, max length +0
       ^-------------|

______

[0,1,1,1,1]
       ^----------------|
[1,0,1,0,1]     | -- match, max length +1
         ^----------------|
```

I should *not* be adding +1 in the final "match" since it's not a subarray anymore. But how do I fix my code to take that case into account?

Comment: The problem with `1 + self.findLength(nums1[1:], nums2[1:])` is that the repeated subarray found in the remaining parts of the arrays might not be at the beginning of the arrays, so you can't just assume these are contiguous with the matching element that's been found.